# Installing and using XeTeX

Tags: xetex, installing, texlive, linux, debian

I have tried to install XeTeX on my Debian system, but this does not appear to work. Here are the steps I took:

- I loaded TeX Live 2011 with `tlmgr -gui`.
- I loaded a repository.
- I selected "not installed packages".
- I selected "collection-xetex".
- I clicked "install".
- The log reported the installation of the included packages, including `xetex`.
- Then a warning appeared saying "Running install collection-xetex failed. Please consult the log window for details."

The log reports the following:

> /usr/local/bin/fmtutil: 1: xetex: not found
>   Error: `xetex -ini  -jobname=xelatex -progname=xelatex -etex xelatex.ini' failed
>
> #
>
> fmtutil: Error! Not all formats have been built successfully.
>   Visit the log files in directory
>     /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-var/web2c
>   for details.
>
> #
>
> This is a summary of all `failed' messages:`
>   xetex -ini  -jobname=xetex -progname=xetex -etex xetex.ini' failed
>   `xetex -ini  -jobname=xelatex -progname=xelatex -etex xelatex.ini' failed
>
> tlmgr: exiting unsuccessfully (status 1).

Some additional details:

- I was unable to find a `xelatex` command anywhere in the path.
- Rebooting the computer resulted in no known change.
- Uninstalling and reinstalling from a different repository produced identical results.
- The TeX Live Manager 2011 GUI currently reports that "collection-xetex" is installed.

What do I need to do to get XeTeX working?

Comment: It seems that you don't have correctly set the `PATH`. Did you choose to make symlinks for the executables?

Comment: During the first install, I set TeX Live to make symlinks. All of the packages from the first install are available. I see now that xelatex is inside my TeX Live directories, but there is no symlink. Is there a setting somewhere that has TeX Live fix symblinks?

Comment: I discovered the "Update Symbolic Links" option in "Actions" > "Handle symlinks in system dirs". It installed fine now.

Comment: @Village: Staying true to this Q&A, I suggest you write up a separate answer to your original question, keeping in mind that it may be helpful to future readers experiencing a similar problem to yours. Self-answers (even if they are accepted) are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem lies in the fact that you chose to create symbolic links for the executables in `/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/<architecture>` to `/usr/local/bin`.

With `tlmgr` there's the possibility to update them, but the action is not performed automatically.

However, my advices are:

1. Always install the full TeX Live
2. Never create symbolic links, particularly on Debian based systems

If you don't have strict space constraints, do a full TeX Live install. It would have avoided the problem of installing the XeTeX subsystem.

Changing what's in `/usr/local/bin` is dangerous as other system utilities *may* choose to install something there. It's better to change the `PATH` variable and the safest method is to write a file `zzz-texlive.sh` containing

```
export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/bin/`uname -i`-linux:$PATH
export MANPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf/doc/man:$MANPATH
export INFOPATH=/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf/doc/info:$INFOPATH
unset TEXINPUTS
unset TEXMFCONFIG
```

and move it into `/etc/profile.d`. After a logout/login cycle, the `PATH` variable will contain the correct directory for the executables.

Comment: This is not the proper way of setting the system-wide `$PATH` on Debian systems. Particularly because `root` needs to have the directory in `$PATH` and root shells don't read `/etc/profile` (IIRC). Instead, it should be added to `/etc/environment`. Note that this file is *not* a shell script but just a list in the form `VARIABLE=<stuff>`. You can also add `MANPATH=<stuff>` and `INFOPATH=<stuff>` here such that `man` and `info` will find the documentation from your TeX Live installation.

Comment: It doesn't help that the documentation on how to install Vanilla TeX Live 2011 on Debian systems ([link](http://www.tug.org/texlive/debian.html#vanilla)) is a bit inaccurate since its sample `texlive-local` file doesn't list `texlive-base-bin`. Caught me off guard when I installed it manually myself. Now if only I could get `sudo` to work with the TeX Live binaries... "`sudo: mkluatexfontdb: command not found`" (but it's in all users' `$PATH`... Weird)

Comment: FWIW, I figured out the problem with `sudo`. It's usually compiled with a built-in "secure path" to prevent accidental or malicious clobbering of programs that are normally executed with `sudo`. Contrast `sudo -i` followed by `echo $PATH` with `sudo env | grep PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

As stated Egred is always better to install the full updated TeX Live. Some times the repositoires are not updated. I have fixed the same issue using this ppa.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/texlive
sudo apt update && sudo apt install texlive-full
```