# Error: \Undefined control sequence \setmainfont in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: fontspec, ubuntu, kile

I am getting error on compiling following Latex code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Code2000}
\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```

Error:

```
\Undefined control sequence \setmainfont{Code2000}
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and Kile Version 2.1.0
Using KDE Development Platform 4.8.5 (4.8.5)

I installed `texlive-full` for `fontspec` package.

What am I missing because of which it is not recognizing the command `\setmainfont` ?

The log file is given below:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.2-0.9995.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian) (format=xelatex 2014.3.20)  20 MAR 2014 20:00
entering extended mode
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**demo_unicode4.tex
(./demo_unicode4.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, farsi, arabic, croatian, bulgarian, ukrainian, russian, czech, slov
ak, danish, dutch, finnish, french, basque, ngerman, german, german-x-2009-06-1
9, ngerman-x-2009-06-19, ibycus, monogreek, greek, ancientgreek, hungarian, san
skrit, italian, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian2a, mongolian, bokmal, nyn
orsk, romanian, irish, coptic, serbian, turkish, welsh, esperanto, uppersorbian
, estonian, indonesian, interlingua, icelandic, kurmanji, slovenian, polish, po
rtuguese, spanish, galician, catalan, swedish, ukenglish, pinyin, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/xelatex/fontspec/fontspec.sty
Package: fontspec 2008/08/09 v1.18 Advanced font selection for XeLaTeX

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2009/01/23 v0.5 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\c@zf@newff=\count88
\c@zf@index=\count89
\c@zf@script=\count90
\c@zf@language=\count91

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/longtableswas/calc.sty
Package: calc 2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count92
\calc@Bcount=\count93
\calc@Adimen=\dimen103
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen104
\calc@Askip=\skip43
\calc@Bskip=\skip44
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 76.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 77.
\calc@Ccount=\count94
\calc@Cskip=\skip45
)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2008/08/13 v2.6a package option processing (HA)

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks14
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks15
\XKV@depth=\count95
File: xkeyval.tex 2008/08/13 v2.6a key=value parser (HA)

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package

(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/xelatex/euenc/eu1enc.def
File: eu1enc.def 2008/03/08 v0.1d Experimental unicode font encoding
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for EU1+lmr on input line 100.


(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/xelatex/euenc/eu1lmr.fd
File: eu1lmr.fd 2007/01/14 v1.3 Font defs for Latin Modern
))
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 1163.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 1166.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 1169.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 1172.

fontspec.cfg loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/xelatex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg))
(./demo_unicode4.aux)
\openout1 = `demo_unicode4.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
Package fontspec Info: Adjusting the maths setup (use [no-math] to avoid this).
 on input line 4.
\symlegacymaths=\mathgroup4
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `legacymaths' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> OT1/cmr/bx/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \colon on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Gamma on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Delta on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Theta on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Lambda on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Xi on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Pi on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Upsilon on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Phi on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Psi on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Omega on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \mathdollar on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `EU1' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/n --> EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Encoding `OT1' has changed to `EU1' for symbol font
(Font)              `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font)                  EU1/lmr/m/n --> EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `normal'
(Font)                  EU1/lmr/m/n --> EU1/lmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/m/it --> EU1/lmr/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/n --> EU1/lmr/bx/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/m/n --> EU1/lmss/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `normal'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> EU1/lmtt/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font)                  EU1/lmr/m/n --> EU1/lmr/bx/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathrm' in version `bold'
(Font)                  EU1/lmr/m/n --> EU1/lmr/bx/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmr/bx/it --> EU1/lmr/bx/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathsf' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmss/bx/n --> EU1/lmss/bx/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Overwriting math alphabet `\mathtt' in version `bold'
(Font)                  OT1/cmtt/m/n --> EU1/lmtt/bx/n on input line 4.

! Font \zf@basefont=Code2000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or insta
lled font not found.
\zf@fontspec ...ntname \zf@suffix " at \f@size pt 
                                                  \unless \ifzf@icu \zf@set@...
l.5 \setmainfont{Code2000}

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.

! Undefined control sequence.
\zf@set@font@type ...onttype \zf@basefont \zf@tfm 
                                                  \or \zf@atsuitrue \ifnum \...
l.5 \setmainfont{Code2000}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Font \zf@basefont=Code2000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or insta
lled font not found.
\zf@fontspec ...ntname \zf@suffix " at \f@size pt 
                                                  \fi \zf@firsttimetrue \zf@...
l.5 \setmainfont{Code2000}

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.

\c@zf@famc@Code2000=\count96
Package fontspec Info: Defining font family for 'Code2000' with options [] on i
nput line 5.
! Font \@tempfontb=Code2000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or instal
led font not found.
\\zf@make@font@shapes ...f@suffix " at \f@size pt 
                                                  \edef \@tempb {\fontname \...
l.5 \setmainfont{Code2000}

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.

! Font \@tempfonta=Code2000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or instal
led font not found.
\\zf@make@font@shapes ...f@suffix " at \f@size pt 
                                                  \edef \@tempa {\fontname \...
l.5 \setmainfont{Code2000}

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.

! Font \@tempfontb=Code2000/B at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or inst
alled font not found.
\\zf@make@font@shapes ...f@suffix " at \f@size pt 
                                                  \edef \@tempb {\fontname \...
l.5 \setmainfont{Code2000}

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.

Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font Code2000/B (it might not exist) o
n input line 5.
! Font \@tempfonta=Code2000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or instal
led font not found.
\\zf@make@font@shapes ...f@suffix " at \f@size pt 
                                                  \edef \@tempa {\fontname \...
l.5 \setmainfont{Code2000}

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.

! Font \@tempfontb=Code2000/I at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or inst
alled font not found.
\\zf@make@font@shapes ...f@suffix " at \f@size pt 
                                                  \edef \@tempb {\fontname \...
l.5 \setmainfont{Code2000}

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.

Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font Code2000/I (it might not exist) o
n input line 5.
! Font \@tempfonta=Code2000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or instal
led font not found.
\\zf@make@font@shapes ...f@suffix " at \f@size pt 
                                                  \edef \@tempa {\fontname \...
l.5 \setmainfont{Code2000}

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.

! Font \@tempfontb=Code2000/BI at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or ins
talled font not found.
\\zf@make@font@shapes ...f@suffix " at \f@size pt 
                                                  \edef \@tempb {\fontname \...
l.5 \setmainfont{Code2000}

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.

Package fontspec Info: Could not resolve font Code2000/BI (it might not exist) 
on input line 5.
! Font EU1/Code2000(0)/m/n/10=Code2000: at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) fi
le or installed font not found.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.5 \setmainfont{Code2000}

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.

Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no b in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no c in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no 1 in font nullfont!
[1

] (./demo_unicode4.aux)

 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
fontspec.sty    2008/08/09 v1.18 Advanced font selection for XeLaTeX
 ifxetex.sty    2009/01/23 v0.5 Provides ifxetex conditional
    calc.sty    2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
 xkeyval.sty    2008/08/13 v2.6a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2008/08/13 v2.6a key=value parser (HA)
 fontenc.sty
  eu1enc.def    2008/03/08 v0.1d Experimental unicode font encoding
  eu1lmr.fd    2007/01/14 v1.3 Font defs for Latin Modern
fontspec.cfg
 ***********

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 2186 strings out of 494665
 44134 string characters out of 1166477
 121792 words of memory out of 3000000
 5460 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+50000
 3648 words of font info for 15 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 669 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 27i,4n,27p,449b,142s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

Output written on demo_unicode4.pdf (1 page).
```

Comment: (1) kile has nothing to do with this. (2) Did you actually run `xelatex` on this? (3) The TeXLive version in 12.04 is very old it may be a better idea to manually install a newer TeXLive.

Comment: Yes, I did run <xelatex> . Can you please direct me in installing a newer version of TexLive ?

Comment: Thanks. I will try installing, but I am getting the same error for \setdefaultfont too

Comment: Two things: 1) add `\listfiles` to your input, miss out the `\setmainfont` line and check what version of `fonstpec` you have from the `File list` in the `.log` file; 2) Use `texdoc fontspec` from the Terminal on your system to get the docs for `fotnspec` as installed on your system, and check what commands should be defined by that version.

Comment: I get the following : fontspec.sty    2008/08/09 v1.18 Advanced font selection for XeLaTeX

Comment: note that is not the format of the TeX undefined command error. The command that is undefined is always the _last_ token on the _first_ line of the error message, in particular that line never ends with `}` (nor does `Undefined` have a `\ `). It would be a lot easier to help if you showed the exact message from the log file.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I have put the exact error only...

Comment: @Swagatika No. That is not a TeX error. Your editor view may be mangling it. Cut and paste the lines from the log file A TeX error starts with a line that starts with `!` and ends with a line that starts with `?`

Comment: for example (this comment formatting will mess it up) I can get the following 3 errors on your file: ! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
                  {article}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.2 \usepackage
               {fontspec}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 \setmainfont
                {Code2000}
?

Comment: No, I am getting only that error. P.S. I am using xelatex to compile this (somewhere, it was advised to use xelatex).

Comment: As I say that error is not from tex (or xetex). Post your entire log file as a code section.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, updated with the log, please check it. Thanks.

Comment: As I said, the undefined command error is telling you that `\zf@tfm ` is undefined. You excluded that part of the message.

Comment: You should always look at the _first_ error reported. (Later errors are often spurious) The first error is not undefined command it is font not found. `! Font \zf@basefont=Code2000 at 10.0pt not loadable:` Either you have not installed Code2000, or teX does not know where it is.

Comment: @daleif, thanks for the link and advice. I followed the step and got the results. But now I am getting another error, `The font "Code2000" cannot be found.` I guess I need to download it. Can you please help me in that ?

Comment: Do you even have that font on your system?

Comment: @daleif  . I solved it finally. After installing recent version of xetex, I downloaded code2000, copied it to `/usr/share/fonts` and the applied the command: `fc-cache -fv`. After that compiling the code using xeLatex succeeded. A request to please put your comment and link as answer, s.t. I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually two-fold.

1. I had an old version of `fontspec` (that comes in `texlive-xetex` package) in my system.
2. The code2000 package was not present in my system.

**1. Making sure you have the up-to-date version of fontspec in your system:**

3. Including the command `\listfiles` in the code helps tracing the correct version of `fontspec.sty` . The log file gave following information:
   `fontspec.sty 2008/08/09 v1.18 Advanced font selection for XeLaTeX –`
4. The next step is to download the up-to-date version of fontspec. Install the latest package of `texlive-xetex` from repository. I followed the answer in [Installing and using XeTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35360/installing-and-using-xetex) to install the package.

**2. Installing code2000 package.**

1. Download the package from its respective link http://www.fonts2u.com/code2000.font
2. Copy to `/usr/share/fonts/`
3. `fc-cache -fv` to refresh font list.

Now the code compiles!

Answer (score 3):

The initial version of the question was misleading as it identified that there was an undefined command error but did not show which command was undefined. The error is

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\zf@set@font@type ...onttype \zf@basefont \zf@tfm 
                                                  \or \zf@atsuitrue \ifnum \...
l.5 \setmainfont{Code2000}
```

So the undefined command is `\zf@tfm`.

However this error is essentially a spurious internal failure caused by not stopping at the first error. (TeX's recovery actions when you scroll past an error are often not particularly useful and just lead to lots of spurious errors).

The first error reported is

```
! Font \zf@basefont=Code2000 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or insta
lled font not found.
\zf@fontspec ...ntname \zf@suffix " at \f@size pt 
                                                  \unless \ifzf@icu \zf@set@...
l.5 \setmainfont{Code2000}
```

which means that it can not find the `Code2000` font either because it is not installed where Tex expects, or not installed at all.

Comment: Thanks. However, I needed a compatible version of texlive-xetex. Once I installed that, it identified correct fontspec.sty where \setmainfont is defined. After that only I am getting the error: `The font "Code2000" cannot be found.  `

Answer (score 0):

For people struggling with font spec package and if you get continuous errors on "undefined control sequence" errors this is what I found out to solve it!

In my case, I discovered after hours that the problem was not Lyx or definitions in the preamble. The origin of the problem is MiKTeX. Sometimes you need to update the packages you are trying to use, to do that:

Go to MiKTeX update
Update source -> I want to get packages from... Use the nearest package repository -> next
Select fontspec package or packages that you find are causing errors -: next
Packages will be updated -> Open lyx and enjoy life again after this shitty errors ;)